# Split XML file into small chunks using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql

i have below PLSQL block to split large XML files into small chunks. it works perfectly to split but xml validation failed because its seperated between xml tags which cause the issue. Any advise to split after end of each tag?

Also i tried to print line by line which works fine but its time consuming process.

```
-- print CLOB using dbms_output in smaller chunks
  procedure print_clob( v_clob in clob ) is
    v_off number := 1;
    v_cnk_size number := 10000;
  begin
    loop
      exit when v_off > dbms_lob.getlength(v_clob);
      dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( v_clob, v_cnk_size, v_off ) );
      v_off := v_off + v_cnk_size;
    end loop;
  end print_clob;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` puts a newline at the end of your chunks and hence the tags are out of place.

Try `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` instead which does not add a default newline character at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately if we use put it allows only 32767 characters in a single line

Comment: @PrakashMani : `PUT` does not eliminate your existing newlines. It simply won't display newline at the end.  What exactly are you trying to do with the xml? and what's the error? Please edit your question and add more details.